# How to install mod_pagespeed on Apache Server on Mac?

Tags: mac, apache

I'm trying to install mod_pagespeed for Apache server, but I can find instructions only for Linux. Is there any tutorial or description on how to do it on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

`mod_pagespeed`is currently not [supported](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/download). However, you can build it from source. Google is describing [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_mod_pagespeed_from_source) how you can do that.

Instead of using apt-get you can install brew. Brew is a lightweight package manager for OS X and can be obtained at their official [homepage](http://www.brew.sh).

I'd recommend to install a Linux distro on a VM and then installing mod_pagespeed as this is way easier, plus you get more support probably.